# I keep getting error when trying to send transaction signed by web3.eth.sign with web3.eth.sendsignedtransaction

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I get the following error:

> Error: TypedTransaction with ID 40 unknown
> at t.TransactionFactory.fromSerializedData

**My code:**

```
const txData = {
      nonce: "0x" + parseInt(nonce, 10).toString(16),
      from: address,
      to: to,
      gasLimit: "0x" + parseInt(gasAmount, 10).toString(16),
      gasPrice: "0x" + parseInt(fee, 10).toString(16),
      value: "0x" + parseInt(balance, 10).toString(16),
    };

    console.log(txData)

    let hexObject = new ethereumjs.Tx(txData);
    let hexString = '0x' + hexObject.serialize().toString('hex'),
        encoded = {
            encoding: 'hex'
        }
    const rawHash = web3.utils.sha3(hexString, encoded);

    console.log('rawHash: ' + rawHash)

    let txHash = await web3.eth.sign(rawHash, address);
    console.log('txHash: ' + txHash)

    const createReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txHash, function (error, hash) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
      else {
        console.log(hash)
      }
    })
```